# Squid 3.5 on Centos7 running as a transparent proxy

Tags: centos, centos7, squid

Hey Serverfault friends;

I'm trying to construct a Squid Proxy acting transparent for all egress traffic flows as a proof of concept in my environment.

I've got one question, and one problem (that I know of!).

The question:

I've got iptables set up to redirect 80 and 443 to 3129 and 3130 respectively, and the http_access works when I *don't* specify `transparent` or `intercept`, which I thought you needed to do?

The problem:

Dealing with the https intercepts. To my understanding, the best bet is to have the squid proxy act as a man-in-the-middle, inspect the request and open it up, and generate a new request to the actual destination server, which, I believe I've done below?

The squid configuration:

```
visible_hostname squid.my.test.tech
#cache deny all

# Log format and rotation
logformat squid %ts.%03tu %6tr %>a %Ss/%03>Hs %<st %rm %ru %ssl::>sni %Sh/%<a %mt
logfile_rotate 10
debug_options rotate=10 ALL,1 11,2
sslproxy_cert_error allow all

# Handling HTTP requests
http_port 3128
http_port 3129
acl allowed_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
acl blocked_http_sites dstdomain "/etc/squid/blacklist.txt"
http_access allow allowed_http_sites
http_access deny blocked_http_sites

# Handling HTTPS requests
sslcrtd_program /usr/local/squid/libexec/security_file_certgen -s /var/lib/ssl_db -M 4MB

https_port 3130 transparent ssl-bump generate-host-certificates=on dynamic_cert_mem_cache_size=16MB cert=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.crt key=/etc/squid/ssl/squid.key
acl allowed_https_sites ssl::server_name "/etc/squid/whitelist.txt"
http_access allow allowed_http_sites
http_access deny blocked_http_sites

always_direct allow all

acl step1 at_step SslBump1

ssl_bump peek step1
ssl_bump bump all

#Drop anything explicitly permitted
http_access deny all
```

In the whitelist is just `.google.com` and `.cern.ch`, and in the blacklist is `.foxnews.com`.

IP Tables are handling the prerouting:

```
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3129
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3130
```

I've generated a self-signed cert, and stored it in the listed directory above `(/etc/squid/ssl)`, copied it to `/etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors` and ran `sudo update-ca-trust extract` to update the CA List for the local host. Then exported copied down the cert to my workstation, added the cert to a trusted authority in firefox (it's a proof of concept, when I go bigger picture we'll look at certificate authority signing--no worries!).

Now I'm hitting the issue where if I set the my local instance of Firefox, http requests work just fine and show up in the logs:

```
1582926343.272    415 172.16.0.199 TCP_MISS/304 264 GET http://info.cern.ch/ - HIER_DIRECT/188.184.64.53 -
```

(I'll skip the log for http hits in the cache)

But https requests show as a TCP_DENIED/200:

```
1582926470.071      1 172.16.0.199 TCP_DENIED/200 0 CONNECT 10.161.128.139:443 - HIER_NONE/- -
```

With the query looking like it's being denied at Squid itself:

```
----------
2020/02/28 21:47:51.554 kid1| 11,2| client_side.cc(2347) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client local=10.161.128.139:443 remote=172.16.0.199:49219 FD 12 flags=33
2020/02/28 21:47:51.554 kid1| 11,2| client_side.cc(2348) parseHttpRequest: HTTP Client REQUEST:
---------
CONNECT 10.161.128.139:443 HTTP/1.12
Host: 10.161.128.139:443
2

----------
```

I've modified the `squid.conf` file extensively to play around with the various options, but it looks like the request is just flat dying at the squid box, and I've not a great deal of experience with squid, and with the hundred or so pages I've dug up on how2squid, I feel like I'm flailing about with guessing-and-checking, so, any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: This is the working example with CentOS/Squid 4 - https://docs.diladele.com/tutorials/transparently_filtering_https_centos/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. I looked through it, and it does pretty well the same thing I'm doing, except uses firewalld rather than IPTables.

"...and after installing certificate as trusted in Root Certification authority there..."

Which I have also done, and it still shows the cert error on my machine, hence my confusion of design.